# How do I edit pre_get_post for the category the user is currently in?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, pre-get-posts

I've got a Woocommerce site that uses categories and products within those categories but how do I get my search form to only display results of products within the category the user currently is in. I've looked around and the closest I've got to is this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','shop_filter_cat');

function shop_filter_cat($query) {
  if (!is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) && $query >is_main_query()) {
    $query->set('tax_query', array(
                array ('taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                   'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => 'type-1'
                             )
                 )
    );   
  }
}
```

And this is brilliant but I don't want to specify the category as 'terms' => 'type-1' I want the search to only show results of products that the user is currently in e.g. if the user selects t-shirts as a category and then searches for 'batman' i want results to only show batman t-shirt results and not batman hat results or any other results. Thank you so much in advance!!

HTML (my searchform.php):

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">

    <input type='textbox' name="s" class="form-control form-inline" id="item-search" value="<?php the_search_query();?>" placeholder="Search items.."/>
    <button class="item-search-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
    <?php
      if ( function_exists( 'woocommerce_product_search' ) ) {
        echo woocommerce_product_search( array( 'limit' => 40 ) );
      }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: If you remove the `action` property of the form, it will post to itself - in this case a category archive - and WordPress will indeed only search in that category.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic so I don't need to use the pre_get_post function above?

Comment: If that solution works to your requirements, then no that's it!

Comment: How did you go with this @T.Doe?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to! With a little understanding of how URLs and query vars work, we can do this entirely within the URL of the page, with no additional PHP code

First we have a URL:

```
example.com/abc/123
```

Then we have a rewrite rule. The rule has a regex pattern that matches the URL, and a second bit that says were all the bits that match go, e.g.

```
"/abc/(.+)" -> "index.php?p=$match[1]"
```

This gives converts `/abc/123` into `index.php?p=123`, which becomes `WP_Query( array( 'p' => 123 ) )`. WordPress then takes a look at the new `WP_Query`, makes it the main query ( the post loop ), and does a little bit of logic to decide which template to load. In this case it sees the `p` and declares this to be a `singular` page, so `single.php` will probably be loaded. See the template hierarchy for more details on that.

The important part is, we can pass extra parameters! `/abc/123` matches, but so does `/abc/123?s=test`. This results in `index.php?p=123&s=test`, and `WP_Query( array( 'p' => 123, 's' => 'test'))`.

Since `s` is the search query param, we can use this new found knowledge to do what you need!

So lets say your user is in the tshrit category, which has the URL:

```
example.com/product-category/tshirts
```

We can use

```
example.com/product-category/tshirts?s=test
```

Now we have a search of the tshirts product category for 'test'. This is great because now we have a URL that's always a search of that category. We could have tracked the tshirt category in a cookie or a session, but this would lead to a single URL showing multiple things to different people, and all the caching problems and SEO issues that come with it.

How would we build the search form?

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="s" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>">
</form>
```

Notice 2 things:

- The text input has the name `s`
- We want to submit the page we're currently on. We could do PHP voodoo to get the current URL, but we don't need to, so we set the `action` attribute to nothing, and let the browser handle it
- I specified the value so that you know what it was you just searched for using `get_search_query`
- This won't work with `POST`